# How to calculate "accurate" surface area of a microporous material using Micromeritics equipment?

Tags: nanotechnology

How do I get an accurate surface area from a nitrogen isotherm?

I've been doing some surface areas on MOFs and upon showing my boss the isotherms he asked me to convert them to show the "range", which will give the most accurate surface area.

I'm using Micromeritics ASAP-2020 software and I believe that you measure this BET range by using points from relative pressures between 0.05 and 0.3. However, this seems to be unsuitable for some microporous compounds?